# Sequelize transaction.commit() doesn't commit the data

Tags: node.js, sql-server, sequelize.js

We use sequelize in NodeJS for talking to the Database (SqlServer). 
We use Sequelize: 4.44.2 and Node: 10.16 
It has been working fine for months. But we faced an issue yesterday which I am not able to find the root cause yet. 
We call a bunch of procedures from our NodeJS application.

```
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction();
try {
      const dbquery = sequelize.query("EXEC proc_a @param1=:param1", { replacements: { param1: a},
            transaction: transaction,
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        });

     const result1 = await Promise.resolve(dbquery);

     const dbquery2 = sequelize.query("EXEC proc_b @param1=:param1", { replacements: { param1: a},
            transaction: transaction,
            type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
        });

     const result2 = await Promise.resolve(dbquery2);
     await transaction.commit();
        // return result1, result2;
} catch(err){
    await transaction.rollback();
}
```

In the above code, looks like the code executed the procs as expected and returned result1, result2. But it did not persist the results of the procedure at `transaction.commit();`

**Troubleshooting steps:**
I can confirm that when one of the procedure fails to execute or when the procedure times out, the transaction rolls back.
But yesterday, the `transaction.commit()` did not throw any error and also it did not persist the results to the database.

Looking at the logs, the `transaction.commit()` seems to have finished within 5 ms.

One another important point is SQL server was under a heavy load at that time. Is there a chance the `transaction.commit()` doesn't throw an error when it fails to commit? or SQL server would have rolled it back for some reason which sequelize failed to throw an error?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put `await` before `sequelize.transaction()`

Instead of

```
const transaction = sequelize.transaction();
```

Try with

```
const transaction = await sequelize.transaction();
```

So instead of getting `transaction` object everywhere you are getting the `Promise` which in turn subject to resolve the `transaction` object.

**UPDATE #1:**
[`sequelize.query`](https://sequelize.org/master/class/lib/sequelize.js~Sequelize.html#instance-method-query) itself returns a `Promise`. So instead of following lines

```
const result1 = await Promise.resolve(dbquery);
const result2 = await Promise.resolve(dbquery2);
```

Use following

```
const result1 = await dbquery;
const result2 = await dbquery2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That was a typo while I copied the code. My code actually has await when it gets the transaction. I have modified the question. Do you have any idea why it might have not persisted actually?

Comment: I have updated my answer in **UPDATE** section, please check @Bala.

Comment: cool. But it doesn't make a difference, correct? I can understand that sequelize.query itself returns a promise. But doing Promise.resolve(query) is not going to do any harm.

Comment: Yes it does no difference in executing the promise. `Promise.resolve(query)` won't do any harm.

Comment: any other reason you can think of why the commit did not persist the records and also did not throw any error? :(